# How to change tint color of Cocoa's NSLevelIndicator?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can the tint color of an NSLevelIndicator be changed at all? (setTintColor doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the green/yellow/red inside it; the control would, on the whole, be rather useless if that was rendered as graphite. In other words; "Outlook not so good."